# Edit datagridview with datasource C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview and it populates with a datasource from SQL. I'm trying to edit a column that contains numbers, but after I click out from the cell, the value becomes 0. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

So far, I just changed the readOnly propierty to false and I read many posts but they talk about ASP.Net and I'm working with Windows Form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Currently there is no useful information in the post to help other users to help you. Please provide more context and take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I dont know what information do you because I think is about some propertie, but if you tell me what do you think I should ask the question I will add that information immediately